# ksh "<<EOF" script to change user

Tags: quoting, ksh, here-document

In the simplest form I am puzzled why this script does not work as expected as a here script changing users with `su - user <<EOF`.

```
su - db2prd<<EOF
PARMDATE=1111111
echo parmdate
echo $PARMDATE
EOF
```

produces output:

```
parmdate
```

and removing the su/EOF part:

```
PARMDATE=1111111
echo parmdate
echo $PARMDATE
```

produces:

```
parmdate
1111111
```

I am unable to figure out why ksh variable assignment is not working and how to make it work, presuming the environment wasn't set, etc.  I have tried everything I can search on.  Variable assignment seems broken in the `su - <<EOF` part.

This is just an example from a much larger script that switches users for some maintenance activities.

Answer (score 1):

Variables are interpreted in a here doc (`<<...`), so you need to escape the ones you don't want evaluated yet.

```
su - db2prd<<EOF
PARMDATE=1111111
echo parmdate
echo \$PARMDATE
EOF
```

Or better, quote the delimiter (here `EOF`) to tell your shell not to perform expansions inside the here-document:

```
su - db2prd<<'EOF'
PARMDATE=1111111
echo parmdate
echo $PARMDATE
EOF
```

Comment: Rather than us `\$` every time you refer to a variable, you can say `su - db2prd << \EOF`.